# MySQL to Hibernate datatype mapping for type "YEAR"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

There's a column in our database which needs to be of type `YEAR`. What is the corresponding Hibernate mapping for the entity? Tried searching all over, but unable to find the details. I am not sure if I need to use anything from `@Temporal` or any other specific type. We are using Hibernate ORM v4.1.7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696506/sql-datatype-how-to-store-a-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [Hibernate UserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom-ut) that takes an Integer to a MySQL YEAR column.

Check for example [Joda Hibernate UserTypes](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core/3.0.0.CR1/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentYearMonthDay.java) which are a good starting point for your custom Hiberante type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did you mean that there's no direct mapping available in Hibernate and I have to write a User Type?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.

Comment: Browsing the MySqlDialect code, it looks like a MySQL YEAR should just naturally map to an Integer.  I haven't used it though, so I can't make a definitive answer.

Comment: I think you are referring to [the YEAR function](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.springsource.com/org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/3.3.2/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java/?v=source), not the YEAR type: registerFunction("year", new StandardSQLFunction("year", Hibernate.INTEGER) );

Comment: I'm pretty sure I used `Integer` for YEAR columns and it worked out of the box. Can't access that project anymore, though. The MySQL [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/year.html) says "You can specify input YEAR values [...] as a 4-digit number", which I'd say should allow `Integer`.

Comment: it seems impossible to me that some of the most popular packages in java development .. or programming in any form, for that matter, are the tools in this question, and yet no one has actually solved this problem  and shared it online yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that as of June 2022, you will need to map your MySQL *Year* datatype to *Integer* datatype in Hibernate.