# Creating table with one column having year datatype

Tags: sql

How do I create a table with one column having year e.g. 2019, 2018 as the only data type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/696506/6877477

Answer (score 1):

You can store a year either as an integer (or smallint, if your database supports it), `decimal(4, 0)`, or as a `char(4)`.

You would use a numeric representation if you planned to do arithmetic on the years -- say adding 3 years or taking the difference.  You would use a string representation if the value were only for show.

Answer (score 0):

Use INT datatype.
There is no need to use Decimal or Varchar

Answer (score 0):

I would use type DATE because you may want to use functions or expressions that use data with type DATE, perhaps in a different table.