# What is the datatype of year in sql database?

Tags: mysql

I am creating an SQL database and got stack on the column of year which is in this format "2009/10". I would like to know which datatype i need to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL DataType - How to store a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696506/sql-datatype-how-to-store-a-year)

Comment: A `string` datatype. Because there's not  a simil type of datatype

Comment: "year which is in this format "2009/10"...that looks like a year and a month, not a year. But yeah it's going to have to be text. There's no specific format which can store a date without the day part - although you could just use datetime and set all the days to 01. And that would mean it's a lot easier to do ordering, filtering etc by the dates. For display purposes you can always just extract the year and month parts alone and print those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Year as datatype, but you want to store value as 2009/10 so you have to give varchar as datatype